# Return a certain section on request

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find out how (and the best way) to return a certain section of a page. I want to know if I can "grab" and return information stored in a HTML section tag.

EDIT:

I've worked on the suggestions given below. So far I have scraped a random piece of the site, which works, but somehow I can't scrape the part I want to.

This is the "random" part:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi94782/ah-mandarijnen-net');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
        echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
        exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$regex = '/<div class="navigation-section navigation-section--home">(.*?)<\/div>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo $list[0];
else
    print "Not found"; 
?>
```

The above code returns:

```
<div class="navigation-section navigation-section--home">
                <a href="/"
                   class="ah-online-icon icon--home link--2 navigation-section__link navigation-section__link--left-icon navigation-section__link--home">Home</a>
        </div>
```

So, that works. Except, the part I want to scrape is:

`<section class="nasa-number"><span>548401</span></section>`

(you can check the [link](https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi94782/ah-mandarijnen-net), if you want to, I am trying to print the grey number near the bottom of the page on the right)

Instead, when I use `$regex = '/<section class="nasa-number">(.*?)<\/section>/s';`, it returns: Not Found

Comment: You are unclear on what you want. It might be helpfull if you can attach some code that you have already done as an example to what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I fully understand what you are saying. I have no code yet, because I have no idea where to start. I can post complete links and show you.

Comment: typically screen scraping with PHP is done with CURL , which can fetch the content. Then you'd need to write code to find the value you are after and assign to a variable, which usually requires some knowledge of regular expressions

Comment: You will need to pull in the full pages content and then parse it down.

Comment: Is the site that you are fetching the content belongs to you or is it the same application ? If not then as @DuaneLortie mentioned fetch the source code and parse the DOM

Comment: @DuaneLortie I have updated my post with results!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need

```
if ( preg_match("/<section class=\"nasa-number\"><span>(.*?)<\/span><\/section>/", $page, $list) ){
    echo $list[1]; 
   } else {
    print "Not found"; 
}
```

This would replace everything after `curl_close($curl);`  Note all I did was  used dbl quotes as a container, so, I had to escape the actual quotes I wanted to match. Tested here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iFn

Comment: Great! I'll test this in a few.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it can be done in many ways
you can use Jquery for that on which you can run onload() fiinction.if there is any number in url you can get it and pass it to other self generated url.
please send me code sample so i can give you best solution based on your problem

Comment: since he's trying to fetch content from a remote site that he no control over, I fail to see how jquery can help, or why you'd use it after you had successfully fetched the remote content